# How can I verify that my PAM configuration works as expected

Tags: pam, testing, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to setup a vsftpd server in a virtual machine and all I can ever get from it is an authentication error (530 Login incorrect). Since I've tried to configure it using virtual users with PAM, I'm wondering if my pam configuration is correct. Unfortunately, vsftpd logs are less than useful for debugging this.

In order to be able to figure out if the problem comes from my pam service of from somewhere else. What command can I use to test my pam service directly.

I've found few options on google (`pamck` and `pam-client`), but none of them seem to be available for my OS (Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 1):

So, after elevating the level of my google-fu, I found out about `pamtester`.

It does everything I need, and it is available from the Ubuntu repositories (and I guess it is also available in other distros). The ubuntu package is simply called `pamtester`